# Multithreading Service for ping, post, get request for large number of sites(5000) .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have a windows service application that gets about 5000 websites addresses from db and depending on settings for current website it tries to ping, post or get commands for it. The main timer checks about every minute the sites to ping and adds them to concurrent stack. Then different tasks try to pop the website fom the stack and use apropriate requesst for them. I can set the different number of tasks for this job I have tried from 50 to 1000. The common problem I get is timer that get's websites to add to stack does it when current sites are to getting pinged. This populates websites stack to ping over an over again before all websites are checked. I am wondering about this problem and the other conneccted with it. So basicaly:

1. Is that good implementation, or it should be done completely different?
2. What would be apropriate parameters to make it work( getting websites timer interval, number of threads) and can them be calculated somehowe beside empirical try outs?
3. Why after setting number of tasks to 50, I get 113 after some time?

Comment: if you keep adding tasks and not allowing older tasks to finish, yes your tasks will grow.  Why not just do one complete pass before starting the next loop of pings.  if one website is already in the queue, it shouldn't be added again.

Comment: The number of tasks trying to pop data to process from queue is constant. I guess you mean that all data should be processed before refreshing data to process?